# Two different transitions on one element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm making a menu with CSS that uses a `transition: all .6s` when the user has scrolled to an amount. In this menu, I have a `ul` that I want to use a fade-transition when hovering. This sadly messes everything up when the user scrolls, the repositioning-effect is delayed. [Example](https://ecoround.se/ny/)

Question is; how can I fix this?

The CSS for the transition when scrolling:

```
.menu, nav, img {
    transition: all .6s;
    -moz-transition: all .6s;
    -o-transition: all .6s;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s;
}
```

The buttons that I want hovering:

```
nav ul li a {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    font-family: dinot;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: ease-in-out .2s;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <nav>
        <a href=""><img src="style/img/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Hem</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Om oss</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tjänster</a></li>
            <li><a href="">projekt</a></li>
            <li><a href="">kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Provide a working fiddle or example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the transition type for the a tags. Here's the fix:

```
nav ul li a {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    font-family: dinot;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color ease-in-out .2s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it, cool to learn a few new things still :)

Comment: Happy to help :)